# What is the best way to check if dynamic web pages are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I only need to check that the page is loaded (without dynamic objects that might be modified after page appears fully)

I know JQuery's function: "ready()"

Will this function be relevant in the described-above case? 
Is there another / better way?

Comment: `window.onload` is not a jQuery function. Concerning it - have you seen the documentation?

Comment: you're right sorry , I meant ready function..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`window.onload` isn't a jQuery function, it's a DOM event.

If using jQuery the best way to check whether the page is loaded is to handle the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event which can be done in various ways

**Shortest**

```
$(function() {
    // DOM initialized
});
```

**Short**

```
$.ready(function() {
    // DOM initialized
});
```

**Longer**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // DOM initialized
});
```

**Longest**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // DOM initialized
});
```

Comment: today I learned about `$.ready`. Thanks. Still I prefer the longer version for clarity.

Comment: `;(function($,undefined){$(function(){ //dom ready})}(jQuery))` is an option aswell

Comment: @VeXii that's effectively the shortest handler inside a module. My answer is pointing out the various shorthands for calling `ready`.

Comment: In addition to @James answer, I would like to clarify that `ready()` states for document being loaded not that EVERYTHING (including images, etc) are loaded, for that, use `$(window).load()`

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that you have an alternative to jQuery' methods . You can use pure JavaScript solution:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){ // defining load event listener

    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed

    // window is loaded , you can use its DOM

},false);
```

This way is good in cases when you , for example , have small/lightweight pages and to load external libraries/frameworks is absolutely unnecessary .