# Replace function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code here:

```
 txtName.value = txtName.value.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, '');
txtURL.value = txtURL.value.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, '');
txtUsage.value = txtUsage.value.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, '');
```

How would I put this in jQuery? I've tried many things and it doesn't work.

```
    txtName = $('#emoteName');
    txtURL = $('#emoteURL');
    txtUsage = $('#emoteUsage');
```

Comment: show us!! what you txtName,txtURL.. is ??

Comment: Related: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Comment: Im not quite sure if I got the question. Exactly what do you need to "put in jQuery". It seems as if you already have those variables declared with the jQuery selector?

Comment: @Eric they aren't declared as jQuery objects, since .value doesn't exist in jQuery but does exist in pure JavaScript...

Comment: why use jQuery? plain old JS is enough here.

Comment: @PeeHaa it's exactly my situation yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390996/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-if-dynamic-web-pages-are-fully-loaded

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. All were good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $txtName = $('#emoteName'),
    $txtUrl = $('#emoteURL'),
    $txtUsage = $('#emoteUsage');
$txtName.val($txtName.val().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, ''));
$txtURL.val($txtURL.val().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, ''));
$txtUsage.val($txtUsage.val().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, ''));
```

Mind take a look at this particular [article](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects) regarding jQuery performance! :)

This should work great too, instead of repeating code, just create an array with your jQuery objects and apply the same replaces to each of them.

```
var $objs = [
        $('#emoteName'),
        $('#emoteUrl'),
        $('#emoteUsage')
    ];

$.each($objs, function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();
    $this.val(val.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, ''));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$txtName.val( $txtName.val().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, '') );
```

It's also common practice to start variable names of jQuery objects with `$`.

Answer (score 2):

use `.val()` for jquery object to get the value.. since your txtName is already a jquery object

```
txtName = $('#emoteName');
```

you can just use `.val()` instead of `value` . `value` is for DOM element

```
txtName.val(txtName.val().replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, ''));
```

do the same for the rest..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the same replacement on all three fields you can do this:

```
$('#emoteName, #emoteURL, #emoteUsage').val(function(i, currentVal) {
    return currentVal.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, '');
});
```

[jQuery's `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) lets you get or set a form element's value. If you [pass it a callback function](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value) that function will be called for each element in the jQuery object, where the current value is passed to the function and whatever the function returns becomes the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Try one:

```
var val = txtName.val();
var new_val = val.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/, '\n').replace(/^\r?\n|\r?\n$/, '');
txtName.val(new_val );
```